# Counting letter occurrences with strings in C

Tags: c, string, words

This program receives a letter and strings and it ends of receiving strings when it is introduced 'FIM' in the string. It keeps the string that repeats more times the letter received and prints it all.
It is giving me one error and I don't know how to solve it (see inline comment):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 101

int conta(char frase[], char letr) {
    int n = 1, i;
    int nmax = 0;
    char primeiro = tolower(frase[0]), stringn[MAX];

    do {
        printf("introduce string: ");
        gets(frase);
        for (i = 1; frase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (tolower(frase[i]) == primeiro)
                n++;
        }
        if (nmax < n) {
            nmax = n;
            stringn[] == frase[];   /*Error!!*/
        }
    } while (frase != 'FIM');

    printf("The string where %c surgiu %d appeared more time is: %c ",
           letr, nmax, stringn);
}

void main() {
    char frase[MAX];
    char letr;

    printf("give a letter:");
    scanf("%c", &letr);
    conta(frase, letr);
}
```

Comment: In code block its saying thats a error before ']' in the line that is saying error

Comment: i've a comment in the line of the error saying error

Comment: This line doesn't look like valid C to me.

Comment: so how can i copy a string so i can copy and save it?

Comment: You might want to use `strcpy`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: can you give me an exemple of the use of strcpy Mr_pouet

Comment: @PedroAlexandre nice job finding the problem. That's what you should have asked! Keep questions concise and direct to the problem, if you want good answers. Check the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Well, now that you have your problem, please use first the search to find if this hasn't been answered before. Try searching for `string copy [c]` for example

Comment: @seleciii44: here is another example erroneous use of the `do / while` loop: this construct seems to induce a certain form of incorrect reasoning, resulting in this kind of error.  I'm referring to the fact that the test for "FIM" is delayed to the end of the loop, whereas it should happen immediately after the infamous `gets`.

Answer (score 4):

`stringn[] == frase[]` is invalid C code, To copy the string, use `strcpy(stringn, frase)`.

Note that there are many other problems with your code:

- `frase != 'FIM'` is incorrect too, but the compiler diagnostic will be difficult to understand because you use an obsolete C syntax.  To compare strings, you should use `strcmp`.  In this case, `strcmp(frase, "FIM") != 0`.  Furthermore, you should not use a `do / while` loop because you must check if the string matches `FIM` before checking for occurrences of `letr`.
- `gets` is obsolete and risky.  Use `fgets` instead.  Note that the string read by `fgets` will contain the `'\n'` at the end if it was typed in.
- you should not pass a naked `char` to `tolower`: if the `char` type is signed, you invoke undefined behavior for negative char values, such as non-ASCII characters. Use this syntax: `tolower((unsigned char)frase[0])`.
- You actually count the occurrences of the first letter of each line, not those of `letr`.  Initialize `primeiro` this way: `primeiro = tolower((unsigned char)letr)`.
- `stringn` should be initialized to an empty string, in case no line has any occurrences of `letr`.  Do this with `strcpy(stringn, "");` or `*stringn = '\0';` or better, define it this way: `char stringn[MAX] = "";`

Comment: "strcpy(stringn, frase)" ? Wouldn't you mean "strcmp(stringn, frase)" ?

Comment: @Smallware: no, study the algorithm: the OP is trying to save the current line when it has the largest number of occurrences.  I don't know why he wrote `string[] == frase[]`, but `strcpy(stringn, frase);` is appropriate for his purpose.